# JSON.stringify() with single quotes on value and no quotes on key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

In Javascript: print a json object

```
var myObject = new Object;
myObject.type = "Fiat";
myObject.model = "500";
myObject.color = "White";
```

in below format

> { type: 'Fiat', model: '500', color: 'White' }

in console.log .

But actual result

> {"type":"Fiat","model":"500","color":"White"}

Challenge is here :

[hackerrank print JSON object](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/javascript-challenges/challenges/objects)

```
function printObjectProperty(myObject) {
  //Write your code here
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)); 
 //OR
console.log("{ type: '"+myObject.type+"', model: '"+myObject.model+"', color: '"+myObject.color+"'}"); //OR THERE COULD BE A BETTER GENERIC SOLUTION
}
```

Comment: Your link is broken. HackerRank links can't be shared.

Comment: I'm not sure that `{ type: 'Fiat', model: '500', color: 'White' }` is valid JSON. It is a valid JS object, though not sure about JSON, that's why `stringify` doesn't produce it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use below code:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);  // {"type":"Fiat","model":"500","color":"White"}
console.log(json);
var unquoted = json.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '$1:');
console.log(unquoted);  // {type:"Fiat",model:"500",color:"White"}
var result = unquoted.replaceAll("\"", "'");
console.log(result); // {type:'Fiat',model:'500',color:'White'}
```

Comment: in this regular expressions , spaces are still missing . spaces before every key and value . I will try to modify this regex .Thank you .

Comment: Line 3 changes like this `json.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, ' $1: ');`

Comment: This solution is wrong when field contains quotes. For example "{a: "a'a"}"

Answer (score 3):

> JSON.stringify() without single quotes on value and no quotes on key

You can't. By-design.

[The JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) requires all properties' names to be enclosed in double-quotes and parsed as JSON strings:

> #### 1. Introduction
>
> [...]
> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, **where a name is a string** and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

> #### 4. Objects
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  **A name is a string**.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following name.

Comment: Okay , But hackerrank has posted this challenge .